# Passing for variable to ng-content

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

How do I pass an ngFor variable to the ng-content template.

Example, the containing-component:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of itemsArray">
       <ng-content></ng-content>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The nested content-component:

```
<div>
    <span *ngIf="item.type_one"></span>
    <span *ngIf="item.type_two"></span>
</div>
```

Example, both:

```
<containing-component>
    <content-component>
    </content-component>
</containing-component>
```

Comment: can you elaborate little more?

Comment: Tomas - see here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c3zz3y?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can not use `ng-content` as dynamic template. Use `ng-template` instead

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of itemsArray">
       <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate; context: { $implicit: item  }">
       </ng-container>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```js
export class ContainingComponent {

  ...

  @ContentChild(TemplateRef, {static: true}) 
  @Input() itemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

So you can reference dynamic template into `containing-component`. In this case, you can wrap ng-template over `content-component`

```html
<containing-component [itemTemplate]="itemTmpl">
</containing-component>

<ng-template #itemTmpl let-data>

    <content-component
      [item]="data">
    </content-component>
</ng-template>
```

Or use `ng-template directly`:

```html
<containing-component 
   [itemTemplate]="itemTmpl"
   [itemArray]="items">
</containing-component>

<ng-template #itemTmpl let-data>
  <div>
    <span *ngIf="data.type_one"></span>
    <span *ngIf="data.type_two"></span>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: There is no `@ContentChild(TemplateRef) ` here . I had to set the ref to the name id of the template - https://i.imgur.com/zO15JIo.jpg.
Is it possible not to reference it to the html variable , but to a TS variable instead ?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbubtu?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Like this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ny3blx?file=src/app/app.component.html. You are mistaking my idea

Comment: You can remove @contentchild . You're not using here any content as an ngcontent. Try and see :)