# How to pass Popover Title,position, text dynamically in html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

In my  project am using popover in that I want to pass the Title,position and text dynamic.i am using ng-content to pass the data.In this code i dono know how to pass it dynamically can anyone please tell me how to achive this?

**landing-component**

```
   <app-pop-over> 
     <app-pop-title> Heading </app-pop-title>
     <app-pop-position> top </app-pop-position>
     <app-pop-text>  gjkgkjgj go oi hoi h </app-pop-text>
  </app-pop-over>
```

**pop-title.component**

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

**pop-position.component**

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

**pop-text.component**

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

**Main Pop-over-component**

```
<button  class="custom-pop-over" data-toggle="popover" [attr.title]="title" data-placement="right" [attr.data-content]="text">jds</button>
```

Comment: this may help you: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878506/angular-2-passing-html-to-ng-content-with-bindings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing for variable to ng-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51807192/passing-for-variable-to-ng-content)

Comment: Am new to this technology can u please help me to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 passing html to ng-content with bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878506/angular-2-passing-html-to-ng-content-with-bindings)

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik Actually i was new to this technology can u please tell me how to use  in my case