# how to pass data to an HTML code that is inside a component?

Tags: angular

In a component I have this:

```
    <sidemenu #side>
      <h1>{{item}}</h1>
    </sidemenu>
```

in sidemenu Component:

```
    aNames=["pedro","juan"]
    .
    .
    .
    <div *ngFor="let item of aNames">
      <ng-content [name]="item"></ng-content>
      <!-- I need:
         <h1>pedro</h1>    
         <h1>juan</h1>    
    -->
    <div>
```

I hope to make myself understood with this example. Actually I have a more complex structure but to make myself understood I put this little example.

I am putting an html code inside a component, and where I include this component I would like some data to be passed to it. In this example I am including the `<ng-content> </ng-content>` (`<h1>`) inside a `* ngFor` so I would like to pass data to this`h1` tag

Comment: Did you try to access the data using @Input() ?

Comment: @Mridul my problem is that i don't know how to do that. `<ng-content [name] = item> </ng-content>`

Comment: @Mridul I will be thankful. But don't forget my problem please. I know how to pass data using @input but in this case I don't know how to do it using the `<ng-content>` I must do it this way.

Comment: @Mridul I must include html code inside the <sidemenu> tag and once inside, I must pass it a value

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51807192/passing-for-variable-to-ng-content

Comment: Maybe you need to find some other way around as it says it's not possible to use this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass data to the component by binding a property like this.

```
<sidemenu [data] = "item">

</sidemenu>
```

Then access that property using `@Input()` decorator in the sidemenu component like this.

```
@Input() data : string;
```

then use can output that data in that component's template using interpolation

```
<h1> {{ data }} </h1>
```